# How to Programatically Get Displayed AG-Grid Cell Contents as Opposed to Actual Value

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I do not want to get the actual value of a cell. I want to get the displayed value.

For example, the actual value is "I am a very long message" but the displayed value is "I am a ver..."

If it helps, I'm trying to make a tooltip appear only when the cell value has been truncated with an ellipsis for display reasons by AG-Grid.